# How is a second material derivative defined?

Tags: calculus, fluid-dynamics, continuum-theory

I am reading a paper and it used a second material derivative written like this:
$$
\dfrac{D^2\delta}{Dt^2}
$$
I know the first order material derivative operator is defined
$$
\dfrac{D\delta}{Dt}=\partial_t\delta + \vec{u}\cdot\nabla\delta
$$
and I know that the second material derivative would just be taking the material derivative again. However, if I wanted to write it a form similar to above it would be
$$
\dfrac{D^2\delta}{Dt^2}=\partial_t\dfrac{D\delta}{Dt}+\vec{u}\cdot\nabla\dfrac{D\delta}{Dt}.
$$
Is there a better way to define/write this? It feels bulky in this form.

Comment: You may want to include more context from the paper. In particular, whether the outer material derivative is intended to apply to the $\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla$ part of the inner material derivative.

Comment: @eyeballfrog It really doesn't provide much more context other than saying $\delta$ is the pertubation and the oscillations are governed by the equation $\dfrac{D^2\delta}{Dt^2}=F_{\delta}$. Its an oceanography paper on a specific wave types dynamics so it doesn't have too much on the mathematics.

Comment: Does it say anything about the equilibrium value of $\mathbf{u}$ that is being perturbed?

Comment: @eyeballfrog the background flow is geostrophic so $\mathbf{u}=(u_g+u_a,v_a,w_a)$ where the a components are the ageostrophic pertubations(the values the flow is being perturbed by).